# Android - Not granted USE_BIOMETRIC

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, manifest

I am checking all permisions from the Manifest with the code bellow. Now I added USE_BIOMETRIC permission, because I want to use fingerprint, but this permission is not granted and I don't know why.

I know that USE_BIOMETRIC is normal permission so it shouldn't be asked and should be granted when it's in the Manifest, but it's not.

Checking for other permissions is working and all are granted or asked for it, only this one is not.

I am testing app on 2 phones, emulated Google pixel with Android 8.0 and API 26 and physical Xiaomi Redmi 5 with Android 8.1 and API 27.

Both phones are using fingerprint to unlock screen.

Permisions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

Code that loads permissions from the manifest and check if is granted or not:

```
fun checkAndRequestPermissions(): Boolean{
    var listPermissionsNeeded = ArrayList<String>()
    val permissions = retrievePermissions(activity.baseContext)
    permissions.forEach {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.baseContext, it) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(it)
            Log.d("Missing permission", it)
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        val array = arrayOfNulls<String>(listPermissionsNeeded.size)
        listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(array)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, array, ConstantsStorage.ACTIVITY_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CODE)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

companion object {

    /**
     * Retrieves permissions listed in the manifest file
     * @param context Context
     * @return Returns String array of permissions
     */
    fun retrievePermissions(context: Context): Array<String> {
        try {
            return context
                    .packageManager
                    .getPackageInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
                    .requestedPermissions
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            throw RuntimeException("This should have never happened.", e)
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `checkSelfPermission()` is only for `dangerous` permissions. Do not use it for `normal` permissions.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hm, you are probably right, why does it work for the rest of permissions when some of them are normal too? I guess there is no way to check if the permission is normal or danger, so i have to add this permision to condition (it != Manifest.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC) whitch i really don't like. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

According to the new policy in Google Console, you couldn't use this permission on the `Manifest`. So you should `Request` and `Check` in **Activity**.

You can use `BiometricManager` to check it:

```
val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)

when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS ->
        Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> {
        // Prompts the user to create credentials that your app accepts.
        val enrollIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_BIOMETRIC_ENROLL).apply {
            putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_BIOMETRIC_AUTHENTICATORS_ALLOWED,
                BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
        }
        startActivityForResult(enrollIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}
```

**Note**: It's very important to add suitable import

```
import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager;
```